# how to recognise these fields correctly (allocated in a javascript variable)?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

i must do parsing in javascript of these fields:

These fields are returned from a server, the format is fixed, the only thing that changes are values returned within [] , but the format is fixed and always the same

```
var var_js=
(02,02) AAAA #33 [00000122] Last Uo
(08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS
(010,23) SD #1 [3^w^^r] YOu an
```

I was trying this for the first field but the console returned "false " and "null".

```
var patt= /^(d{2},d{2})\s\w{4}\s\#d{2}\s\[d{8}]\s\Last Uo$/gm;
logger.debug(var_js.match(patt));
logger.debug(patt.test(var_js));
```

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: so you need a regex to match any of the given lines in var_js?

Comment: @caramba exactly

Comment: can you edit the `var_js` in order to represent a js variable?
The way is rendered, it's hard to tell what its content.

Comment: If `var_js` is a string, please add backticks around them.

Comment: can you please update the question and explain which values are possible inside `[ here ]` as now it's like everything from small to big, which are the restrictions there?

Comment: @adiga var_js is a variable that allocates the results from a server that are rapresented from these fields

Comment: @CodeRage var_js is a variable that storages the result from a server

Comment: is `var_js`:
var var_js=  
"(02,02) AAAA #33 [00000122] Last Uo" +  
"(08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS" +  
"(010,23) SD #1 [3^w^^r] YOu an";  
or  
var var_js=  
"(02,02) AAAA #33 [00000122] Last Uo\n" +  
"(08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS\n" +  
"(010,23) SD #1 [3^w^^r] YOu an";  
  
What you have written it's not a valid js code.

Comment: @caramba certainly, done. so the values have always the same format (Eight digits,ecc..).. what changes each time  is the value storaged within [here]

Comment: @CodeRage in fact it isn't a javascript code..... var_js rappresents a variable that storages this content that is returned from a query to a server, but it is allocated in javascript through this variable

Comment: You could also match all of them like this `^\(\d{2,3},\d{2,}\)\s+[A-Z]{2,4}\s#\d+\s*\[[^\][]*\]\s+\w+\s+\w+` https://regex101.com/r/KJPgpy/1

Comment: @Nedved95 That is because match returns an array, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match and see the results here https://ideone.com/df0a1j

Comment: Are you using this in Google Apps Script?

Comment: In this patt -> var patt= /^\(\d{2,3},\d{2,}\)\s+[A-Z]{2,4}\s#\d+\s*\[[^\][]*\]\s+\w+\s+\w+/gm; , i don't have understood this part  : [[^\][]*\] , what's means ? @Thefourthbird thanks

Comment: @Nedved95 I means that it will match from `[` till `]` without matching chars `[` or `]` in between.

Comment: i don't have understood, sorry :( @Thefourthbird

Comment: @Nedved95 I have added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match all 3 strings, you could use

```
^\(\d{2,3},\d{2}\)\s+[A-Z]{2,4}\s#\d+\s*\[[^\][]*\]\s+\w+\s+\w+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cYuY3k/1)

The pattern will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `\(\d{2,3},\d{2,}\)` Match `(`, then 2-3 digits, a comma, 2 digits and `)`
- `\s+[A-Z]{2,4}` Match 1+ whitespace chars and 2-4 times an uppercase char A-Z
- `\s#` match a single whitespace char and `#`
- `\d+\s*` Match 1+ digits and optional whitspace chars
- `\[[^\][]*\]` Match from `[....]` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `\s+\w+\s+\w+` Match 2 times 1+ whitspace chars and 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

```js
var var_js = `(02,02) AAAA #33 [00000122] Last Uo
(08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS
(010,23) SD #1 [3^w^^r] YOu an`;

var patt = /^\(\d{2,3},\d{2}\)\s+[A-Z]{2,4}\s#\d+\s*\[[^\][]*\]\s+\w+\s+\w+/gm;
var_js.match(patt).forEach(m => console.log(m));
```

Comment: m is been filled with all three lines, but i want to print only one line, how can i do? (i.e the second line) @Thefourthbird

Comment: Using `var_js.match(patt)[1]` will give you the second line

Comment: ok solved, thanks a lot, one last piece of information, how can I create a JSON dynamically, i.e. by allocating "Attribute" and "Value"? (i.e Attributes are "Last Uo",UI AS,You An, while values are those allocated into square brackets)? @Thefourthbird have you indications for me? i would need a json with properties that are those specificated and i need to allocate to it the values that are stored into brackets, how can i do?

Comment: var json={ Last Uo: value, UI AS: value ,ecc..} in this sense @Thefourthbird

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, to allocate as a value the one returned with var.match.[1] etc. ... but assuming that you do not know the number of rows, that can be more than 3, how can I do? I mean in this case I know it is 3, but suppose that there are even more, but I do not know the actual number .. how can I set it? thank you ... I am aware of the use of stringify() as a method, but at the conceptual level how can I set it?
 @Thefourthbird , yes if you want cancel comments

Comment: because moreover with this instruction "var_js.match(patt)[1]"  I print all also the attribute , instead I want only the value .  @Thefourthbird

Comment: @Nedved95 If you open the link https://regex101.com/r/CtHh3z/1 you can see that on the left top you can generate example code like this https://regex101.com/r/CtHh3z/1/codegen?language=javascript Now you can create your specific code using this example which will show you all the values :-)

Comment: Why i don't ask questions any more? @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 0):

For the first field this works:

```
^\(\d{2},\d{2}\)\s\w{4}\s\#\d{2}\s\[\d{8}\]\sLast Uo$
```

You had made a bunch of mistakes

- its `\d` not `d` to match digits
- You hadnt escaped the braces, either `()` nor `[]`

Live example: https://regexr.com/5lerh

This pattern obviously wont work for the other 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You were mainly missing a few `\`. This RegEx will match any of the given lines, thus resulting in three matches...

```js
const regex = /^\(\d{2,3}\,\d{2}\) \w{2,4} \#\d{1,2} ?\[(\d{8}|\d{4}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}|\d{1}\^w\^\^r)\] (Last Uo|UI AS|YOu an)/gm;
const str = `(02,02) AAAA #33 [00000122] Last Uo
(08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS
(010,23) SD #1 [3^w^^r] YOu an`;
let matches;

while ((matches = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(matches);
}
```

you can play with the RegEx here: https://regex101.com/r/pHSRYv/1

if you want only to match the first line you can do like so

```js
const regex = /^\(\d{2}\,\d{2}\) \w{2,4} \#\d{1,2} ?\[\d{8}\] (Last Uo)/gm;
const str = `(02,02) AAAA #33 [00000122] Last Uo
(08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS
(010,23) SD #1 [3^w^^r] YOu an`;
let matches;

while ((matches = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(matches);
}
```

You can also wrap the entire RegEx from above in `( )` and then check for full matches. You can add "dummy" strings inside the string and see how it works

```js
const regex = /(^\(\d{2,3}\,\d{2}\) \w{2,4} \#\d{1,2} ?\[(\d{8}|\d{4}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}|\d{1}\^w\^\^r)\] (Last Uo|UI AS|YOu an))/gm;
const str = `
//what is this line? <> it's nothing
(02,02) AAAA #33 [00000122] Last Uo
and again, do not match me please
(08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS
oooh this works also (08,00) DF #2[1111.888.88] UI AS
(010,23) SD #1 [3^w^^r] YOu an
`;
let matches;

while ((matches = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: you can replace `let` with `var`. I assume the reason for error though is something else. As you can see you can "Run code snippet" which works without errors

Comment: @Nedved95 it's hard to say because I can not reproduce the problem myself. You have to make a fiddle or something. See also here you can click on console and see it works: https://jsfiddle.net/d840Lrug/

Comment: @Nedved95 so what are the rules? it can be any charachter or sign or number with a given length? if yes what is the min and max length? if no or you are not sure make a list of some possible scenarios which need to be matched

Comment: @Nedved95 well if you don't know an option would be to say but you can match almost anything if you add the `{0,10}` option which means 0 - 10 times so maybe the character is not even there. see this: https://regex101.com/r/0yHOkQ/1 with the regex`\[\d{0,10}\^{0,10}[a-zA-Z]{0,10}\^{0,10}[a-zA-Z]{0,10}\]`

Comment: @Nedved95 so you now need to match stuff you mentioned nowhere even just close in the question?